# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject parse response - help parse one section

Tags: c#, parsing, json-deserialization

I dont understand where mistake, please help. Another sections I parse and all ok. But can`t parse this section - always get null

```json
{
   "delivery_options":{
      "Na adres":{
         "Paczka pocztowa ekonomiczna, Paczka48":{
            "price":180,
            "time":"śr. 5 kwi. - czw. 6 kwi. u Ciebie"
         }
      },
      "Na adres za pobraniem":{
         "Paczka pocztowa ekonomiczna pobranie, Paczka48":{
            "price":200,
            "time":"śr. 5 kwi. - czw. 6 kwi. u Ciebie"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```
    public DeliveryDetails delivery_options { get; set; }

    public class DeliveryDetails
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DeliveryOptionsItem>> DeliveryOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

Where my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Based on provided JSON structure - you don't need the `DeliveryDetails`, `delivery_options` should be of `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DeliveryOptionsItem>>` type:

```cs
class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DeliveryOptionsItem>> delivery_options { get; set; }
}
```

For example:

```cs
var js = """
{
   "delivery_options":{
      "Na adres":{
         "Paczka pocztowa ekonomiczna, Paczka48":{
            "price":180,
            "time":"śr. 5 kwi. - czw. 6 kwi. u Ciebie"
         }
      },
      "Na adres za pobraniem":{
         "Paczka pocztowa ekonomiczna pobranie, Paczka48":{
            "price":200,
            "time":"śr. 5 kwi. - czw. 6 kwi. u Ciebie"
         }
      }
   }
}
""";

var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(js);
Console.WriteLine(root.delivery_options.Count); // prints "2"
```

P.S.

Consider using [standard C# coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) and to help your deserializer library to handle it you can either mark it with corresponding attribute (can be `JsonPropertyName` or `JsonProperty` based on the lib) or provide the naming convention.